# CHtml::listData with a complex $textField

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'd like to use a couple of attributes from within a model as `textField`. Something like this:

```
$form->dropDownList(
    $formModel, 
    'ref_attribute', 
    CHtml::listData(
        User::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'attribute1 ASC, attribute2 ASC')), 
        'id', 
        'attribute1 attribute2 (attribute3)'), 
    array()
);
```

so that `'attribute1 attribute2 (attribute3)'` is automatically translated into the correct attribute values. I have tried writing it "as is" (`'attribute1 attribute2 (attribute3)'`), and creating a middle function inside the model (`fullName()`), but nothing seemed to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible by creating a extra method in your Model class. You have to create a getter and use it [with the yii magic](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-property) as a normal property.

So you have in your template:

```
$form->dropDownList(
    $formModel, 
    'ref_attribute', 
    CHtml::listData(
        User::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'attribute1 ASC, attribute2 ASC')), 
        'id', 
        'fullName'), 
    array()
);
```

And in your model:

```
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->attribute1.' '.$this->attribute2.' ('.$this->attribute3.')';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP of version greater than 5.3 then you can use anonymous functions:

```
$form->dropDownList(
    $formModel, 
    'ref_attribute', 
    CHtml::listData(
        User::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'attribute1 ASC, attribute2 ASC')), 
        'id', 
        function($model){
            return $model->attribute1.' '.$model->attribute2.' ('.$this->attribute3.')';
        }
    ), 
    array()
);
```